# normal cdf and pdf functions in Pyomo

Tags: pdf, pyomo, normal-distribution, cdf

I am working on a mathematical model in pyomo. There are parameters that are based on a normal distribution. The input for these distributions is not a simple numerical number, but it's another parameter that is defined in pyomo.
I imported the Statistics package to use normal distribution but I get this error:
Cannot convert non-constant Pyomo expression (0  <  s) to bool.
This error is usually caused by using a Var, unit, or mutable Param in a
Boolean context such as an "if" statement, or when checking container
membership or equality.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I share it here for others if they had the same question.
I think the easiest approach is working with python (Numpy ), generating whatever you want, then assigning it to pyomo objects. I tried this and it worked very well.